# How to find all mongoDB documents based on geolocation

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, react-native

I'm using the react geosuggest package to save locations of my events in MongoDB. The package takes data from Google places and each time I store it, it gets stored like this:

```
"_id": "vvagbSbEginyrQGK8",
"name": "test3",
"googleLocation": {
    "label": "Testaccio, Roma, Italia",
    "placeId": "ChIJE47T5i5gLxMRhiCxCUAFq4Q",
    "isFixture": false,
    "gmaps": {
        "address_components": [
            {
                "long_name": "Monte Testaccio",
                "short_name": "Monte Testaccio",
                "types": [
                    "establishment",
                    "natural_feature"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Rome",
                "short_name": "Rome",
                "types": [
                    "locality",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Rome",
                "short_name": "Rome",
                "types": [
                    "administrative_area_level_3",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Metropolitan City of Rome",
                "short_name": "RM",
                "types": [
                    "administrative_area_level_2",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Lazio",
                "short_name": "Lazio",
                "types": [
                    "administrative_area_level_1",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Italia",
                "short_name": "IT",
                "types": [
                    "country",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "00153",
                "short_name": "00153",
                "types": [
                    "postal_code"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "formatted_address": "Monte Testaccio, 00153 Rome, Italia",
        "geometry": {
            "location": {},
            "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport": {
                "f": {
                    "b": 41.87460301970851,
                    "f": 41.87730098029151
                },
                "b": {
                    "b": 12.474345019708494,
                    "f": 12.477042980291571
                }
            }
        },
        "place_id": "ChIJE47T5i5gLxMRhiCxCUAFq4Q",
        "types": [
            "establishment",
            "natural_feature"
        ]
    },
    "location": {
        "lat": 41.87595200000001,
        "lng": 12.475693999999976
    }
}
```

I've tried a lot of different queries with the mongodb near query, but I can't figure it out. Anyone know about a query that will for example find all documents within 10000 meter based on longitude and latitude that I send in.

Answer (score 2):

According to the current version of mongodb, it has Gospatial query operators and you can achieve what you need after modifying the collection which contains the places as following:

First you should create "2dsphere" index for the collection, let's name it "places" as following:

```
db.places.createIndex( { loc : "2dsphere" } );
/*
the document should contain "loc" property as following:
{
  loc : { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.88, 40.78 ] },
  //+ the other needed properties.
}
*/
```

Then for a specific origin and distance range, you can apply the following query:

```
db.places.find(
{
   loc:
   { $near :
     {
        $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ -73.9667, 40.78 ] 
        //the origin point.
        },
        $minDistance: 1000, //in meter
        $maxDistance: 5000  //in meter
      }
   }
}
)
```

Note that the coordinates ordered as following [long,lat].

for more information you can check the mongodb document in the following link:

1. [2Dshpere indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/2dsphere/)
2. [Geospatial operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/)